# Compute the moment generating function of $Y = X_1X_2 + X_1X_3 + X_2X_3$

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

### Suppose $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3$ are independent and $N(0, 1)$-distributed. Compute the moment generating function of $Y = X_1X_2 + X_1X_3 + X_2X_3$.

1. *I know that any $X_iX_j$ with $i \not =j $ is a joint normal with variables $(x_i,x_j)$*
2. *I also know the formula of the moment generating function of a normal
   distribution.*

   Furthermore, I know that if $Y_1,…, Y_n$ are independent $N(0,1)$, that is, $Y = (Y_1,…,Y_n )´$ are $N(0,I)$ by definition, the moment generating  function of Y is given by $$e^{\frac{1}{2}\mathbf t' \mathbf t}$$

I thought about using the pdf's and the definition of a moment generating function but it proved to be a **really** tedious process jacked of multiple integrations.

Does anyone know how to easily solve this problem with some relatively simple lines? (Especially using the multivariate normal properties and matrices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1\\
1&0&1\\
1&1&0
\end{bmatrix},\quad X=\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\
X_2\\
X_3
\end{bmatrix}$$
the other choices of $A$ would give the correct $Y$, but I need it to be symmetric later. Then
$$
Y=\frac{1}{2}X^TAX
$$
The pdf for 3d standard normal distribution
$$
p(x)=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^Tx\right]
$$
The moment generating function for y is then
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda y})=\int d^3x(2\pi)^{-3/2}\exp\left[\frac{\lambda}{2}x^TAx\right]\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^Tx\right]=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int d^3x\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^T(I-\lambda A)x\right]
$$
The above integral is solved by the following for a real symmetric matrix $M$
$$
\int d^3x\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^TMx\right]=\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^3}{\det M}}
$$
Inserting we find
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda y})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(I-\lambda A)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+1}}
$$

Comment: I am not too familiar with the MGF but if you plug in $\lambda = 1$, then $E[e^Y]$ should still be a real number, right?  Your final expression would evaluate to an imaginary number $1 / \sqrt{-4}$.

Comment: Not quite, $\mathbb{E}(y^n)=\left.\frac{d^n}{d\lambda^n}\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda y})\right|_{\lambda=0}$. So if you don't differentiate you just get the normalization 1, then differentiate once you get the mean and so on.

Comment: I wasn't talking about $E[Y^n]$.  I was talking about $E[e^Y]$.  Let $Z = e^Y$, and $Z$ is a well-defined real-valued random variable.  It is not a-priori clear that $Z$ has finite mean, but it is still curious that your formula gives $E[Z] = 1/\sqrt{-4}$.

Comment: Arhh I get what you mean, it's because the the integral then diverges. The integral formula in the post uses that I can diagonalize the matrix. For $I-\lambda A$ I get the following eigenvalues $-2\lambda+1,1+\lambda,1+\lambda$, thus for positive $\lambda$ it diverges.

Comment: OK I am not familiar with the integral formula you quoted (nor do I have the background to understand it).  But usually in this kind of thing you need *all* eigenvalues to be in a certain "good" set, like $(-1,+1)$ or $(-\infty, 0)$.  However, for any $\lambda$ the eigenvalues $1+\lambda$ and $1-2\lambda$ will be on different sides of $1$.  I guess I am surprised that this would qualify as a "good" set...?  Can you maybe state precisely the conditions under which the integral formula holds?

Comment: All the eigenvalues need to be positive, so I wasn't quite correct when I said positive $\lambda$ doesn't work, e.g. $\lambda=2/5$ works. It just boils down to normal gaussian integral $\int e^{-ax^2}\,dx$, where you also need $a>0$.

Comment: On your symmetric matrix do you mean 1 instead of 0 on the 3rd column second row?

Comment: You’re right, I’ve made the edit

Comment: Maybe you should add the range of $\lambda$ while writing the final answer. That would be more complete.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some smarter ways to solve this, but repeated applications of the [tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)
$$\mathbf E [X] = \mathbf E[\mathbf E[X|Y]]$$
 will give you the result.

Take the definition of the moment generating function
$$M_Y(t) = \mathbf E[\mathrm e^{t Y}]$$
and, in the first step, condition on $X_2$ and $X_3$; you get that
$$\begin{aligned}
M_Y(t) &= \mathbf E\big[ \mathbf E [ \mathrm e^{t Y} | X_2, X_3]\big]\\
&= \mathbf E\big[ \mathbf E [ \mathrm e^{t X_1(X_2 + X_3)} | X_2, X_3] \mathrm e^{t X_2X_3}\big]
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that, conditioned on $X_2$ and $X_3$, the random variable $X_1(X_2+X_3)$ is $N\big(0,(X_2+X_3)^2\big)$, so (using the definition of the MGF of a normal random variable)
$$ \mathbf E [ \mathrm e^{t X_1(X_2 + X_3)} | X_2, X_3] = \mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2}(X_2 + X_3)^2t^2}$$
So we have that
$$M_Y(t) = \mathbf{E} \big[ \mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2}(X_2 + X_3)^2t^2 + tX_2 X_3}\big].$$

Apply the same trick again to integrate out $X_2$:
$$\begin{aligned}
M_Y(t) &= \mathbf{E} \big[ \mathbf E[\mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2}(X_2 + X_3)^2t^2 + tX_2 X_3}|X_3]\big]\\
&=\mathbf{E} \big[ \mathbf E[\mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2}X_2^2 t^2  + X_2 X_3t^2 + tX_2 X_3}|X_3]\mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2} X_3^2t^2}\big].
\end{aligned}$$
The conditional expectation can be computed writing out the integral and [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) at the exponent; you may need to prove the following intermediate result

> Let $X\sim N(0, 1)$, then
>   $$ \mathbf{E} [ \mathrm e^{ \frac{1}2 a X^2 + b X}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a}}\mathrm e^{\frac{1}{2}\frac{b^2}{1-a}}$$

Doing the same "complete the square" once more to integrate out $X_3$ should give you the final answer.